# how to add items from server to Recyclerviewe when click on Load More?

Tags: load, limit, add-in, android-recyclerview, scrollstotop

i want to load data from server with limit 10 then when user scrolls to the end of the list , new data(json) with limit 10 load and add to RecyclerView
how can i do that

Comment: add code of  what you have done.

Comment: you can not give your question part in answer area. remove it & edit to your question with your code